# I can make a 2 pubspec.yaml one for Web and another to Mobile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a stable project that I made with Flutter for Android and IOS. It is working fine, currently, I'm using flutter 2.2.3 and I'm managed to make work on the web too.

The problem is that when I run the release mode or debug mode I see that some packages that I don't use on Flutter Web simple import because I already have this package that my Flutter Mobile use.

I really need to make a new flutter project just to copy and paste my code? Or there is a solution for that?

Comment: we can trick something like this. we will create 2 pubspec.yaml, one will real other will be `pubspecW.yaml,`. we will change the file name on build time. :)

Comment: Where i set and how i change the pubspec?

Answer (score 0):

For that matter, a solution is to use conditional imports.

```
import <packageA>
if (kIsWeb)
   import <packageB>
   import <packageC>
```